# Absolute recursive tar without parent directories?

Tags: linux, tar

I have a directory structure that looks something like this:

```
/var/www/website/index.php
/var/www/website/home.php
/var/www/website/whatever.text
/var/www/website/.htaccess
/var/www/website/images/
/var/www/website/images/image1.jpg
/var/www/website/images/image2.jpg
```

I want to tar the website directory recursively, but I don't want to include the parent structure. If I do this:

```
tar -zcvf /tmp/mytar.tar.gz /var/www/website/*
```

Then all the files have the entire `/var/www/website/` parent structure in the tar file. The only way I can do what I want is to:

```
cd /var/www/website
tar -zcvf /tmp/mytar.tar.gz *
```

That way, there is no parent directory structure in the tar file.

Is it possible accomplish what I need without having to `cd` into the directory first?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

GNU tar has a `-C` option for this.

```
-C, --directory=DIR
    change to directory DIR
```

So you could do something like:

```
tar -C /var/www/website -zcvf /tmp/mytar.tar.gz .
```

Untarring (you will do that eventually) is the same:

```
tar -C /var/www/website -zxvf /tmp/mytar.tar.gz
```

Comment: Ah I've used the `-C` option for untarring in the past. Didn't think to try it with tarring as well. Thanks!